# Why if $U=\mathrm{span} \{(0,1)\}$ and $W=\mathrm{span} \{(1,0)\}$ then $U \cup W\neq \mathbb R^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why if $U=\mathrm{span}\{0,1\}$ and $W=\mathrm{span}\{1,0\}$ then $U \cup W\neq \mathbb R^2$?

As far as I understand $\mathbb R^2=\mathrm{span}\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ while $U \cup W=\mathrm{span}\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. However, I saw an example that $(1,1)\notin U \cup W$.

Comment: If you mean $U=\mathrm{span}(\{(0,1)\}),$ $W=\mathrm{span}(\{(1,0)\}),$ the reason is because you'll end up with a union of two lines when you take this union, rather than the whole plane. That is, you'll have the $x$ and $y$-axes, to use common parlance, but nothing else.

Comment: @Weaam I use "\mathrm{span}" for that, since there's no "\span" command.

Comment: I edited the question, indeed I meant $U=\mathrm{span}\{(0,1)\}$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet `\operatorname{span}` will usually produce better spacing.

Comment: @amd To tell you the truth, for "span" I can't see any difference between the two, but I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to study about Direct Sums of the vector spaces and how is it different from the union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a misunderstanding. Maybe $U=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}$ while $W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}$. But $$
\mathbb{R}^2=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1),(1,0)\}\neq\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}\cup\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}=U\cup W.
$$
Consider that $U\cup W$ is the union of the two axis, but the two axis are not the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$$
U\cup W=\{(x,y)~:~x=0\}\cup\{(x,y)~:~y=0\}=\{(x,y)~:~x=0\vee y=0\}
$$
This way you see that for each $(x,y)\in U\cup W$ there is either $x=0$ or $y=0$. Therefore $(1,1)\notin U\cup W$.

Comment: So what would be the span of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: I already wrote that i.e. $\mathbb{R}^2=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

" $U\cup W=span\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ " -> 
That part is incorrect, actually:

$U\cup W=span\{(1,0)\} \cup span\{(0,1)\}$ is exact. 
Which is not the same. The union of two vector space is generally not a vector space.

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is the whole plan but $U \cup W$  is only the union of the two axes.

But notice that we have:
$\mathbb{R}^2=span\{U\cup W\}$